# How to customize the number of one frame on beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

How to set a number of one frame on beamer, please?

I've tried this :

> \setcounter{page}{19}

But it wouldn't work. Any brilliant idea, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\def\insertframenumber{215}
\def\inserttotalframenumber{1346}
```

perhaps using a group to keep the change local, if required:

```
{
\def\insertframenumber{215}
\def\inserttotalframenumber{1346}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
}
```

Comment: but that wouldn't change the total. For example, if I want to change the last frame's numbering, I need also to change its total

Comment: @dgs please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I need to wait 2 minutes to set it as accepted. @Gonzolo, in a Thesis or Scientific presentation does the bibliography's set before the frame of thanking of the jury attention, please?

Comment: @dgs That might vary, but usually the "Thanks" frame is the last one; I particularly don't like that "Thanks" frame and I don't use it.